# Как создать ответ после обработки исключения в фильтре?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Использую asp. net mvc 5 (сам проект типа web api, а не mvc). Хочу сделать фильтр исключений, который бы записывал в лог ошибку, а затем возвращал ответ.

Из действий контроллера ответы возвращаю через специальные методы, вроде Ok, InternalServerError. Для фильтра использую IExceptionFilter из пространства System.Web.Http.Filters, поскольку проект типа web api, а не mvc.

Вопрос в том, как вообще правильно организовать это дело. Допустим, в лог я записал, и хочу вернуть клиенту объект вроде { Result: false, Message: "Не удалось выполнить запрос: ошибка такая-то" }. Должен ли я сгенерировать ответ в самом фильтре, или может быть это вообще делается не тут, а просто заполняется какое-нибудь свойство, а ответ делается где-то еще.

Вот грубый пример кода:
Контроллер:

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
[BeforeResponseExceptionFilter]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(string name, int age)
    {
        var pers = new Person() { Name = name, Age = age };

        throw new Exception("Я тебе покушать принес");

        return Ok(pers);
    }
}
```

Фильтр:

```
public class BeforeResponseExceptionFilter : Attribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Конечная цель - чтобы можно было выбрасывать исключения в случае логических ошибок, снабжая их пояснительным текстом для администратора и пользователя (отдельные тексты) и чтобы эти исключения ловились в едином месте, без необходимости делать это в каждом экшене. Текст администратора логируем в файл, а текст пользователя - возвращаем в http-ответе.

Comment: `проект типа web api, а не mvc` вы не поверите... А вообще покажите код примера того, что вы делаете.

Comment: @aepot, в этих шаблонах действительно используются разные классы для фильтров :)

Comment: @Grundy я к тому что одно другому не мешает, не взаимоисключающие факторы.

Comment: @aepot, там потом в вопросе еще раз уточняется по поводу namespace, поэтому кажется корректно все указано :) а не просто так :)

Comment: @aepot добавил условный пример с пояснением вопроса в конце

Comment: [Exception Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters)

Comment: @Grundy, это должно работать и в MVC 5?

Comment: @Shebbyman, ты же говорил про web api :) но суть остается той же

Comment: Да, но это web api в пределах фреймворка MVC 5, а ссылка просто на Core, поэтому и уточнил

Comment: Вы задались правильным вопросом. Создание исключений с описательными сообщениями о причинах ошибок очень важно. И по этому поводу я хочу посоветовать статью [The art of designing exceptions](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/the-art-of-designing-exceptions/). И вообще весь блог неплохой.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `throw new SomethingWentWrongException("Something went wrong.");`